# Параллельное ожидание завершения

Tags: c#

Имеется несколько объектов типа [`System.Diagnostic.Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx). Требуется обеспечить ожидание завершения этих процессов с помощью `WaitForExit(int milliseconds)`, но так чтобы суммарное время не превышало в разы `milliseconds`. Т.е. по сути это действие надо распараллелить.

Какой канонический способ существуют для этого в *C#*? В первую очередь интересует вариант, доступный для реализации в *VS2013* (*.Net 4.0*). В качестве дополнения можно привести наиболее современный вариант, если он будет отличаться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться событием `Exited` и старым-добрым `ManualResetEvent`/`ManualResetEventSlim`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var reset1 = new ManualResetEventSlim();
        var reset2 = new ManualResetEventSlim();

        var p1 = new Process();
        p1.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe");
        p1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        p1.Exited += (s, e) => reset1.Set();
        p1.Start();

        var p2 = new Process();
        p2.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe");
        p2.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        p2.Exited += (s, e) => reset2.Set();
        p2.Start();

        var onTime = WaitHandle.WaitAll(new[] { reset1.WaitHandle, reset2.WaitHandle }, 10000);

        Console.WriteLine($"Completed on time: {onTime}");
    }
}
```

---

Также нынче в тренде ожидать с помощью современного API: оборачивая события в `TaskCompletionSource` (хотя, конечно, иногда это чересчур навороченно). Можно воспользоваться событием `Exited`, `TaskCompletionSource` и методом `Task.WaitAny()`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tcs1 = new TaskCompletionSource<byte>();
        var tcs2 = new TaskCompletionSource<byte>();

        var p1 = new Process();
        p1.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe");
        p1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        p1.Exited += (s, e) => tcs1.SetResult(0);
        p1.Start();

        var p2 = new Process();
        p2.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe");
        p2.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        p2.Exited += (s, e) => tcs2.SetResult(0);
        p2.Start();

        var completedTaskIndex = Task.WaitAny(Task.Delay(10000), tcs1.Task, tcs2.Task);

        Console.WriteLine($"Completed on time: {completedTaskIndex > 0}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попрбуйте WaitHandle.WaitAll, а в качестве списка хэндлов соберите Process.Handle всех процессов.

Comment: А ничего, что `WaitAll` ожидает тип `WaitHandle[]`, а `Process.Handle` имеет тип `IntPtr`?

Comment: Это просто - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852305/how-to-wait-for-the-first-of-the-2-a-process-and-an-eventwaithandle

Comment: Можно написать свой наследник WaitHandle, а можно и задействовать ManualResetEvent